# Dr Java program gets errors when writing query to MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, drjava

I made a program that makes a simple GUI for a login form. Just for testing purposes I made it so when you click the "Login" button, Java should just print out the query results from MySQL database. In MySQL I have a database schema called "test" and a table called "login". The login table only has 1 row: "1, angelo, password" under the columns: loginID, Username and Password.

MySQL Workbench Username is root. Host is localhost port 3306. I made sure MySQL Server is currently running (In the Task Manager Services "MYSSQLSERVER" is running)

I have the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" in my "Extra Classpath" folder for DrJava (that's the software I'm using to program).

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;




public class swing_sample extends JFrame
{
  //declaring our swing components
  JLabel l_name,l_pass, title;
  JTextField t_name;
  JPasswordField t_pass;     //A special JTextField but hides input text
  JButton button, button2;
  Container c;

  //a inner class to handling ActionEvents
  handler handle;

  //a separate class for processing database connection and authentication
  //database db;

  swing_sample()
  {
    super("Login form");

    c=getContentPane();
    //c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.setLayout(null);

    //extra classes
    //db=new database();
    handle =new handler();

    //swing components
    title = new JLabel("EAP Admin Log-In form");
    l_name=new JLabel("Username");
    l_pass=new JLabel("Password");
    t_name=new JTextField(10);
    t_pass=new JPasswordField(10);
    button=new JButton("Login");

    //adding actionlistener to the button
    button.addActionListener(handle);

    //add to contaienr
    c.add(title);
    c.add(l_name);
    c.add(t_name);
    c.add(l_pass);
    c.add(t_pass);
    c.add(button);
    //visual
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,530);


    //set positions, Size, 
    title.setLocation(175, 0); 
    title.setSize(200, 200);
    l_name.setLocation(50, 110); 
    l_name.setSize(100, 100);
    l_pass.setLocation(50, 210); 
    l_pass.setSize(100, 100);
    t_name.setLocation(200, 150); 
    t_name.setSize(200, 25);
    t_pass.setLocation(200, 250); 
    t_pass.setSize(200, 25);
    button.setLocation(100, 400); 
    button.setSize(100, 25);



  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    swing_sample sample=new swing_sample();
  }

  //an inner class .You can also write as a separate class
  class handler implements ActionListener
  {
    //must implement method
    //This is triggered whenever the user clicks the login button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
      //checks if the button clicked
      if(ae.getSource()==button)
      {
        char[] temp_pwd=t_pass.getPassword();
        String pwd=null;
        pwd=String.copyValueOf(temp_pwd);
        System.out.println("Username,Pwd:"+t_name.getText()+","+pwd);



        Connection connection = null;

        try {
          // Load the JDBC driver
          String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // MySQL MM JDBC driver

          Class.forName(driverName);

          // Create a connection to the database
          String serverName = "localhost:3306";
          String mydatabase = "test";
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +  "/" + mydatabase; // a JDBC url
          String username = "root";
          String password = "";
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);


          System.out.println(url);

          Statement st = connection.createStatement();


ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select Username, Password from login where loginID   = 1");

          while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println( rs.getString("Username"));
          }
          st.close();
          rs.close();
          connection.close(); 


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();        
          // Could not find the database driver
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();     
          // Could not connect to the database
        }





     //The entered username and password are sent via "checkLogin()" which return `boolean`
        /*        if(db.checkLogin(t_name.getText(), pwd))
         {
         //a pop-up box
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have logged in successfully","Success",
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         }
         else
         {
         //a pop-up box
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!","Failed!!",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }

         }//if
         */


      }//method

    }//inner class
  }//class
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
at edu.rice.cs.plt.reflect.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:148)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at swing_sample$handler.actionPerformed(swing_sample.java:111)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struggling with - Class not found exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699796/struggling-with-class-not-found-exception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-java)

Comment: the problem looks kinda similar but I'm using Dr Java and not NetBeans so I don't know if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not placed the mysql connector jar file in your classpath. Try adding that jar and run your program. You can download the mysql connector official jdbc jar from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Comment: I already have "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" in my Extra Classpath that I set up in DrJava by going Edit -> Preferences -> Add Extra Classpath